# Can Mingw32/Msys run dos/cmd.exe executables with ampersand in arguments?

Tags: mingw, msysgit

This is a similar question to :[Can Mingw32/Msys run dos/cmd.exe executables without screwing up the arguments?](https://superuser.com/questions/558469/can-mingw32-msys-run-dos-cmd-exe-executables-without-screwing-up-the-arguments/559728#559728?newreg=d3f64722d70f4ea3b22e8878b439c48d)

I'm trying to launch outlook from the mingw shell. I want to launch a new message window with the TOEMAIL and SUBJECT populated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
start Outlook //c ipm.note //m mailto:johndoe@domain.com&subject=Hello
```

This starts the new message window with the right TO address, but no subject. Also outputs

```
[1] 17960
```

I've also tried:

```
start Outlook //c ipm.note //m mailto:johndoe@domain.com/&subject=Hello
```

This starts the new message window with the TO address "johndoe@domain.com/", still no subject, and...

```
[2] 13764
[1]    Done         start Outlook //c ipm.note //m mailto:johndoe@domain.com
```

I've tried a couple other variations, but I think the main problem is I'm unable to escape the ampersand.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
start Outlook //c ipm.note //m "mailto:johndoe@domain.com^&subject=Hello"
```

It was the ^&, and it had to be in quotes.